# Windows Identity Foundation - Programmatically read claim types from web.config

Tags: wif

What is the best way to programmatically read the claim types found in the Web.config?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  You're not reading claims for the web.config.  You're reading the claims from a token, and that's all handled through WIF.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I am referring to the claims that are generated by the fedutil.exe in the web.config. I want to be able to compare them as valid claims against what I get from the STS. On a different topic, I read your post (http://garrettvlieger.com/blog/2010/03/refreshing-claims-in-a-wif-claims-aware-application/) and it isn't working for me, as far as refreshing the claims. Any ideas?

Comment: I wanted this more for a verification check than anything. I'm actually checking the real claims via ClaimsIdentity object and somebody had changed a claim description which was causing some errors. Also, Garret, I take back what I said about your post as I got it working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but I don't think the claim types listed under applicationService/claimTypeRequested in the web.config are actually used by WIF, they're only used by FedUtil.exe when generating your application's federation metadata document. Therefore I don't think WIF exposes them anywhere under FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration like one might expect.

You can always just crack open the web.config and scan for them yourself, like so:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~").FilePath);
XmlNamespaceManager docNs = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
docNs.AddNamespace("fed", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
XmlNodeList claimsNodes = doc.SelectNodes(@"/fed:configuration/fed:microsoft.identityModel/fed:service[count(@name)=0 or @name='']/fed:applicationService/fed:claimTypeRequired/fed:claimType", docNs);
```

Comment: You are correct but Iw as wondering if anyone had a way to read the claims from web.config other than parsing it as xml. I want this mainly because someone changed a claim out from under me and I was hoping to write a quick test to validate the claims.

Comment: It sounds like you can achieve what you're trying to do by parsing the web.config as XML. May I ask why you're apprehensive to do so?

Comment: Just looking for a strongly typed way I suppose. If there is a built-in object (apparently there isn't) I would prefer to use that.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew is correct - the list in the web.config is only used for metadata.

If you wanted to, you could [Access The Claims in an ASP.NET Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517271.aspx), scan the web.config and compare.